# SpriteKit presentScene not working with transition, only without

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I have my `SKView` as an `IBOutlet` and a delegate that allows scenes to change the current scene as follows:

```swift
// this code is inside the view controller
func changeScene(to sceneType: GameScene.Type) {
    let sceneName = NSStringFromClass(sceneType).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    let scene = sceneType.init(fileNamed: sceneName)!
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    scene.dialogueDelegate = self.dialogueView
    scene.sceneDelegate = self
    self.hudScene.hudDelegate = scene
    self.actionButtonScene.actionButtonDelegate = scene
    self.gameView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 2))
}
```

I am calling this function once when the game starts (and it works) and once when the player falls out of the scene:

```swift
// this code is inside the scene
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if self.player.position.y < -self.size.height / 2 {
        self.player.removeFromParent()
        self.sceneDelegate?.changeScene(to: Self.self)
    }
}
```

But the second time it does nothing. The code gets executed, but the scene is not presented. Removing the `SKTransition` seems to solve the problem, but why is the transition an issue here?

Comment: Maybe the sceneDelegate is uninstantiated? SKTransitions are working perfectly for me PTAL of this example: https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/blob/master/SKTransitions/SKTransitions/GameScene.swift

Comment: sceneDelegate is instantiated, the function gets called and it works perfectly without the transition